# Debug assertion failed: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

in C++ on following code:

```
class Foo {
    vector<Foo*> otherFoos;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  Foo* data = new Foo[5];
  delete data;
}
```

I get this following error: 
[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I have no idea what is wrong with my code whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write `delete [] data;`. `delete` for `new`, `delete[]` for `new[]`.